# Haskell type checking/pattern matching

Tags: haskell

The following Haskell code complains at the 2nd last line, when I am trying to check if the expression evaluates to something of the form Cons _ _. Haskell's error message is: "Pattern syntax in expression context: _" - what I'm wondering is - is there a way to accomplish what I am trying to do??? It seems what I am trying to do is check the type of an expression at run-time, which from what I have read likely means I could be programming this better? However, since I'm a beginner I don't know if that's what I'm doing or not, especially since I have been trying to do this for about the last hour.

```
data Val = Num Int | Nil | Cons Val Val
    deriving (Eq, Show, Read)

interpret_expr :: Prog -> Vars -> Expr -> Val
interpret_expr _ _ (Isnum NilE) = Num 0
interpret_expr _ _ (Isnum (ConsE _ _)) = Num 0
interpret_expr _ _ (Isnum (NumE _)) = Num 1
interpret_expr prog vars (Isnum expr)
    | interpret_expr prog vars expr == Nil = Num 0
    | interpret_expr prog vars expr == Cons _ _ = Num 0
    | otherwise = Num 1
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
interpret_expr prog vars (Isnum expr)
    | interpret_expr prog vars expr == Nil = Num 0
    | interpret_expr prog vars expr == Cons _ _ = Num 0
    | otherwise = Num 1
```

Your usage of guards is invalid. You cannot apply a function (here it is `(==)` function) to a pattern. That is, you cannot compare (using `Eq` typeclass) something and `Cons _ _`. You need to pattern match again, and it can be done using `case .. of`:

```
interpret_expr prog vars (Isnum expr) = case interpret_expr prog vars expr of
    Nil -> Num 0
    Cons _ _ -> Num 0
    _ -> Num 1
```

Answer (score 5):

Checking if a value is of a particular constructor is a common thing.  Many times you will see a handwritten fragment in the form:

```
isCons (Cons _ _) = True
isCons _          = False
```

and it would be used as:

```
| isCons (interpret_expr prog vars expr) = Num 0
```

This is common enough that various source to source rewrite tools will add `is[Some Constructor]` functions (ex: `derive` and `DriFT`).  I am partial to the template haskell solutions (because they don't require running an external tool, not because TH is very clean or stable).  If you install the `derive` library then your code could look like:

```
import Data.Derive.Is
import Data.DeriveTH
import Language.Haskell.TH

data Val = ...
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

$(derive makeIs ''Val)
```

Comment: Though this answer is great, I've selected the other one as it is simpler and is the simplest way of doing what I want to do. However, I am so glad you told me that because I am 100% sure I am eventually going to need this, and initially I thought I was going to be told nope you can't check constructors you silly newbie, time to rewrite that whole thing (hundreds of lines long)!!!

Comment: Vladimir's answer os absolutely the right solution.  I focused very narrowly on the line you called out, glad you found it interesting.